# Converting finite state machine diagram to Verilog code

Tags: verilog, finite-automata, state-machine

I need to convert the following finite state diagram into Verilog code.
[image]

I've included the code I've written so far below. It looks to me like I've implemented all of the logic correctly and the code works for the first few input combinations. It eventually fails however and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
module FiniteStateMachine(output reg out_z, input in_x, in_y, clk, reset_b);

    parameter   S0 = 2'b00, S1 = 2'b01, S2 = 2'b10, S3 = 2'b11;
    reg         state;

    always @(posedge clk, negedge reset_b) begin

        // set state
        if (reset_b || !in_x) state <= S0;
        else
            case (state)
                S0: state <= (in_y == 1) ? S1 : S3;
                S1: state <= S2;
                S2: state <= S3;
                S3: state <= S3;
            endcase

        // set output
        out_z <= (state == S2 || state == S3) ? 1 : 0;

    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "works" and "fails".

Comment: and which signal is supposed to switch the states? `case (state)` is incorrect. i guess you wanted to use something like `case ({in_x,in_y})` instead. Also i would suggest to have different names for states and conditions.

Comment: @dave_59 the test bench written to test it registers an incorrect output.

Comment: @Serge the state should change on the rising edge of the clock, or reset to state 0 on the falling edge of the reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a number of problems with your implementation as it is now:

1. Your `state` variable is only one bit wide when it needs to be two: `reg state` -> `reg [1:0] state`
2. Its likely that you dont actually want to have `out_z` be a register as it should follow the state on the same clock, not a clock cycle after.
3. Your `reset_b` logic is backwards, for negedge resets, you need to checkfor assertion via `!reset_b` or `~reset_b`.
4. As has been mentioned, you really shouldn't combine asynchronous resets with any synchronous input, even a synchronous reset, as you have done with `reset_b` and `in_x`. While this will work fine in simulation, most synthesis tools will likely be unable to handle it properly. When learning Verilog, I made this same mistake and it took days to discover and correct.

Heres a cleaner version of your code with this fixes implemented and commented so you can see these 4 points:

```
module FiniteStateMachine(output reg out_z, input in_x, in_y, clk, reset_b);

  parameter S0 = 2'b00, S1 = 2'b01, S2 = 2'b10, S3 = 2'b11;
  reg [1:0] state; // Fix state variable

  // Set output combinationally (no need for turning operator)
  always @(*) begin
    out_z = (state == S2 || state == S3);
  end

  always @(posedge clk, negedge reset_b) begin
    // Invert the logic for reset and keep it separate
    if (!reset_b) begin
      state <= S0;
    end
    else begin
      // You can case on inputs as was suggested, but I think casing on state is fine
      // I include only logic for changing state
      case (state)
        S0: begin
          if (in_x && in_y) begin
            state <= S1;
          end
          else if (in_x && !in_y) begin
            state <= S3;
          end
        end
        S1: begin
          if (in_x) begin
            state <= S2;
          end
          else begin
            state <= S0;
          end
        end
        S2:  begin
          if (in_x) begin
            state <= S3;
          end
          else begin
            state <= S0;
          end
        end
        S3: begin
          if (!in_x) begin
            state <= S0;
          end
        end
      endcase
    end
  end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've tried to simplify the FSM by treating `in_x` as a secondary reset. I don't think this simplification is correct, and in any case you're trying to be too clever. Just write out all the transitions for each case, either as a nested `case` statement or as a series of `if`s under each state. For example:

```
case (state)
  S0: case ({in_x, in_y})
    2'b00: state <= S0;
    2'b01: state <= S0;
    2'b10: state <= S3;
    2'b11: state <= S1;
  endcase
  S2: case ({in_x, in_y})
    …
```

Comment: I implemented this logic and tested the code again but the problem with my code appears to be with the value that _out_z_ is being set to.